# creating new element will delete first element in a list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have made a class -WhiteList - that contains data which is read from an xml file. I want to make a list of these elements, but after the first element is added to the list, I create a new element for data which erases the contens of the first element in the list. I.E. It seems that the new (elements) re-creates a reference to the element in the list.

Code snippet:

```
namespace WhiteList
{
   public class WhiteListElement
   {
      private const byte EQL = 0;  
      private const byte CTN = 1;  
      private const byte COMMON_NAME = 0;  
      private const byte ORG = 1;  
      private const byte ORG_UNIT = 2;  
      private const byte LOC = 3;  
      private const byte STATE = 4; 
      private const byte COUNTRY = 5;   

      private static string[,] Subject;  
      private static string[,] Issuer;   

      private static string MinTlsLevel; 
      private static string Customer;


      public WhiteListElement()
      {
         Subject = new string[6, 2];
         Issuer = new string[6, 2];
         Customer = "";
         MinTlsLevel = "";
      }

      //---- set/get functions ---- example
      public string GetCommonName(bool SubjectVal, bool Name)
      {  
         if (true == SubjectVal) { if (true == Name) return Subject[COMMON_NAME, 0]; else return Subject[COMMON_NAME, 1]; }
         else { if (true == Name) return Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 0]; else return Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 1]; }
      }
      public void SetCommonName(bool SubjectVal, bool Name, string NewValue)
      {  
         if (true == SubjectVal) { if (true == Name) Subject[COMMON_NAME, 0] = NewValue; else Subject[COMMON_NAME, 1] = NewValue; }
         else { if (true == Name) Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 0] = NewValue; else Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 1] = NewValue; }
      }

   }
   class Program
   {
      public static void CreateWhiteList()
      {
         try
         {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("WhiteList.xml"))
            {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                  {
                     if (reader.Name == "Kunder")
                     {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                           if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                           {
                              XElement el = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
                              if (el != null)
                              {
                                 WhiteListElement elem = new WhiteListElement();

                                 var noderef = el.FirstNode;
                                 elem.SetCustomer(el.Name.ToString());
                                 while (noderef.NextNode != null)
                                 {
                                    noderef = noderef.NextNode;
                                    string nodestring = noderef.ToString();
                                    if (nodestring[0] == '<')
                                    {
                                       int startindx, stopindx;
                                       string tag = nodestring.Substring(3);
                                       string data;
                                       tag = tag.Substring(0, tag.IndexOf('_'));
                                       startindx = nodestring.IndexOf('\"') + 1;
                                       stopindx = (nodestring.Substring(startindx)).IndexOf('\"');
                                       data = nodestring.Substring(startindx, stopindx);
                                       switch (tag)
                                       {
                                          case "CERTLVL": elem.SetCertLvl(data); break;     
                                          case "CN": if (nodestring[1] == 'S') elem.SetCommonName(true, true, data); if (nodestring[1] == 'I') elem.SetCommonName(false, true, data); break;
                                          case "OU": if (nodestring[1] == 'S') elem.SetOrgUnit(true, true, data); if (nodestring[1] == 'I') elem.SetOrgUnit(false, true, data); break;
                                          case "O": if (nodestring[1] == 'S') elem.SetOrg(true, true, data); if (nodestring[1] == 'I') elem.SetOrg(false, true, data); break;
                                          case "L": if (nodestring[1] == 'S') elem.SetLocation(true, true, data); if (nodestring[1] == 'I') elem.SetLocation(false, true, data); break;
                                          case "S": if (nodestring[1] == 'S') elem.SetState(true, true, data); if (nodestring[1] == 'I') elem.SetState(false, true, data); break;
                                          case "C": if (nodestring[1] == 'S') elem.SetCountry(true, true, data); if (nodestring[1] == 'I') elem.SetCountry(false, true, data); break;
                                       }
                                    }

                                 }


                                 CustomerList.Add(elem);
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); throw (ex); }
      }

      public static List<WhiteListElement>CustomerList = null;

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         CustomerList = new List<WhiteListElement>();
         CreateWhiteList();
      }
   }
}
```

------------- Code snippet end.

The problem occur after the first element is put in the list (CustomerList.Add(elem)) and returns to the line "WhiteListElement elem = new WhiteListElement();". This will delete the elements in CustomerList[0] and when putting data into elem afterwards, it is inserted into both elem and CustomerList[0], ending up with two identical elements in the list.

I have even tried to put an elem = null after adding elem just to try to erase the reference, but that didn't work

What am I doing wrong?

/Karsten

Comment: please add :  // Put Data into Whitelist object - This works. , acutally , its the only important part

Comment: I don't think that there is enough information in your question.  The code seems fine as it is.

Comment: I expanded on the class too.  But as I said: Reading from the xls file will put the data into the object/class as wanted. It is the list that is ruined when new'ing element. The code above is all the code I have. It looks fine, but will not work.

Comment: @KarstenL this looks fine to me... unless you are doing something strange in the code you haven't shown, this should work

Comment: For me, it's quite hard to see where the problem may be because of how you are parsing your XML - I think if you did this in a more concise manner (LINQ to XML?) it might be a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  private static string[,] Subject;  
  private static string[,] Issuer;   

  private static string MinTlsLevel; 
  private static string Customer;
```

your problem come from here, static members are shared through all instances of a class thus when you edit the second , you erase the first, your class should be like this

```
public class WhiteListElement
   {
      private const byte EQL = 0;  
      private const byte CTN = 1;  
      private const byte COMMON_NAME = 0;  
      private const byte ORG = 1;  
      private const byte ORG_UNIT = 2;  
      private const byte LOC = 3;  
      private const byte STATE = 4; 
      private const byte COUNTRY = 5;   

      private string[,] Subject;  
      private string[,] Issuer;   

      private string MinTlsLevel; 
      private string Customer;


      public WhiteListElement()
      {
         Subject = new string[6, 2];
         Issuer = new string[6, 2];
         Customer = "";
         MinTlsLevel = "";
      }

      //---- set/get functions ---- example
      public string GetCommonName(bool SubjectVal, bool Name)
      {  
         if (true == SubjectVal) { if (true == Name) return Subject[COMMON_NAME, 0]; else return Subject[COMMON_NAME, 1]; }
         else { if (true == Name) return Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 0]; else return Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 1]; }
      }
      public void SetCommonName(bool SubjectVal, bool Name, string NewValue)
      {  
         if (true == SubjectVal) { if (true == Name) Subject[COMMON_NAME, 0] = NewValue; else Subject[COMMON_NAME, 1] = NewValue; }
         else { if (true == Name) Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 0] = NewValue; else Issuer[COMMON_NAME, 1] = NewValue; }
      }

   }
```

edit : you can read more on static in the reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/98f28cdx.aspx

especially:

> While an instance of a class contains a separate copy of all instance fields of the class, there is only one copy of each static field.
>
> It is not possible to use this to reference static methods or property accessors.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I think Boo's answer solves your problem, but I thought I would at least suggest a more object orientated approach that might make working with / debugging this problem easier in the future:

```
public class WhiteListElement
{
    public string CertLevel;

    public static WhiteListElement Create(XElement xml)
    {
        WhiteListElement element = new WhiteListElement();
        element.CertLevel = xml.Attribute("CERTLVL").Value;
        // Put data into object...
        return element;
    }
}

public class WhiteList
{
    public List<WhiteListElement> Elements = new List<WhiteListElement>();

    public static WhiteList Create(string xmlUri)
    {
        WhiteList whiteList = new WhiteList();
        whiteList.Elements.AddRange(XElement.Load(xmlUri).Descendants("Kunder")
            .Where(xmlElement => xmlElement != null)
            .Select(xmlElement => WhiteListElement.Create(xmlElement)));
        return whiteList;
    }
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
WhiteList list = WhiteList.Create("WhiteList.xml");
string certLevel1 = list.Elements[0].CertLevel;
```

With the example XML:

```
<Title>
  <Kunder CERTLVL="123"></Kunder>
  <Kunder CERTLVL="456"></Kunder>
</Title >
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out. My class is an SSL class that I want to use for individual "customers", given in the structure
<WhitLst>
  <Kunder>
    <Kellog>
    <S_CERTLVL_EQL> "TLS12" </S_CERTLVL_EQL>
           <S_CN_CTN> "bdc 4 kellogs" </S_CN_CTN>
           <S_C_EQL> "DK" </S_C_EQL> 
           <I_C_EQL> "US" </I_C_EQL>
           <I_O_CTN> "Entrust"</I_O_CTN>
 </Kellog>
         <M>
            .. dta
        </M>
          ..
  </Kunder>
</WhitLst>

I am used to (ANSI) C, but after 20 years want to try C#, so there are some challenges :-) ... thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: No problem - one thing I found quite intimidating when I first stated learning C# was LINQ (.Where, .Select in my example), but once you get your head round it, it can be really powerful for tasks like this.